# jQuery hiding nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 levels of divs. When i select button from action div there should be shown some options(important: hiding last shown options(and categories )), when i click some option button there are shown categories. How to make it to look much cleaner than to write all variations in onclick property?(this is just example, i have much bigger example here - many options, and many categories for each options.)

```
<div id="action">
    <p:commandButton onclick="$('#option1').show(); "$('#option2').hide();"/>
    <p:commandButton onclick="$('#option1').hide(); "$('#option2').show();"/>
</div>

<div id="option1" style="display:none">
    <p:commandButton onclick="...?"/> 
    <p:commandButton onclick="...?"/>
</div>

<div id="option2" style="display:none">
    <p:commandButton onclick="...?"/>
    <p:commandButton onclick="...?"/>
</div>

<div id="option1category1" style="display:none">
    <p:commandButton />
</div>
<div id="option1category2" style="display:none">
    <p:commandButton />
</div>
<div id="option2category1" style="display:none">
    <p:commandButton />
</div>
```

Comment: Assign a class to the button and use $(".button-class").toggle() ?

Comment: But where, why? toogle ll show elements which should be hided. i could always use $(".category").hide()   and show only one need  $("#option1category1").show()  but its kinda lame?

Comment: Button elements are all wrong!!! It does not exist <button3> element for example, you should write it as <button class="button3">.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lgz2y/5/

Comment: My bad i wrote it half pseudocode there should be everywhere p:commandButton. I ll replace it.

Comment: @user2771738 did you have a look at the above fiddle

Comment: Ye thats great, but i wonder is there similar property to data-target in primefaces commnadButton ?

Comment: I wonder is data-target is some predefined property(I dont have this property in autocomplete in netbeans)?? Or we can create own attributes just adding some property in definition of button like you did with data-target??

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your markup. The `button` tag is not used the same as the `img` tag. Button tags have a starting and closing element.

Also, your divs need to be closed with an `</div>` tag in stead of `<div>`.

I sketched out some basic functionality you are probably looking for.

```
$('#button1').click(function(){    
    $('div[id^="option"]').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
});

$('#button2').click(function(){   
    $('div[id^="option"]').hide();
    $('#option2').show();
});
```

This code hides all divs that start their ID with option, and then shows one of them.

Check the fiddle for the complete markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/ef4ux/

Comment: I fixed all errors. About the solution, i have more than 50 buttons. I am looking for some better solution than to create click function for each button.

Comment: @user2771738 Then you'll need an identifier like data-target as Arun P suggested.

Comment: Yup now only left is there such property in some of primefaces buttons :)